# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem when I run the below code:

```
function newUser($email,$pwd,$pwd2,$firstname,$surname,$isAdmin=0){
  $email = $this->verify('Email',$email,10,40);
  $pwd = $this->verify('Password',$pwd,6,20);
  $pwd2 = $this->verify('Password',$pwd2,6,20);
  $firstname = $this->strToTitle($this->verify('Name',$firstname,2,40));
  $surname = $this->strToTitle($this->verify('Title',$surname,2,40));
  if ($pwd != $pwd2)
    return -1;
    $key=md5("secure")
  $result = $this->query("INSERT INTO user (email, pw, firstname, surname, isAdmin) VALUES (".$email.", AES_ENCRYPT(".$pwd.",".$key."), ".$firstname.", ".$surname.", ".$isAdmin.")");
  if (mysql_affected_rows()>0)
    return mysql_insert_id();
  else
    return 0;
}
```

It always prompt "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in F:\xampp\htdocs\sql.php on line 76"

Any one can keep me some advise??
Many thanks!!

Comment: The line 76 represent this line:
$result = $this->query("INSERT INTO user (email, pw, firstname, surname, isAdmin) VALUES (".$email.", AES_ENCRYPT(".$pwd.",".$key."), ".$firstname.", ".$surname.", ".$isAdmin.")");

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A semi-colon is missing on the line assigning the result of the query to `$result`, it should be:

```
$key = md5("secure");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$key=md5("secure")
```

is causing the error. You forgot your semi-colon. This is why having an IDE with a built-in PHP parser will save you time and effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I used 2 hrs to find the problem!!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `;` after `$key=md5("secure")`.

The easiest way to find out where you've missed semicolon is to look at the preceding line of the line where error occurred.